# Iframe: Cut off the bottom

Tags: html, iframe

I have iframed an RSS feed and I want to cut off specific part on it.

Here's the iframe..

```
<iframe src="http://rss.ighome.com/gadgets/rss.aspx?desc=1&count=9&color=000&fs=12px&fw=bold&refresh=0&url=http%3a%2f%2fnews.yahoo.com%2frss%2f" 
    width="500"
    height="400px">
</iframe>
```

If you scroll down to the bottom of the RSS feed, there is a word "More" that I want to cut out. How can I do so?

Comment: I don't think you can since you don't own the content of it

Comment: The best you would be able to do is use a plugin to load the data from the feed and then push that to your screen in the format you want - [have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660774/can-javascript-load-xml-data-from-a-third-party-domain) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery) for some ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the content of the `iframe`, but you can place something over it so it hides the link.

Something like [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/8Laeh/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://rss.ighome.com/gadgets/rss.aspx?desc=1&count=9&color=000&fs=12px&fw=bold&refresh=0&url=http%3a%2f%2fnews.yahoo.com%2frss%2f" width="500" height="400px"></iframe>
    <div id="iframe-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#iframe-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
#iframe-overlay { /* Adjust values as needed */
    height:17px;
    width:480px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    top:-24px;
    left:5px;
}
```